# Alexa error with session attributes

Tags: node.js, async-await, alexa-skills-kit

I am using [Alexa Node.js sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-sdk), to implement a skill. On session start (at `LaunchRequest` intent), I want to store some variables in the session attributes. As per [the blog here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/2279543b-ed7b-48b4-a3aa-d273f7aab609/alexa-skill-recipe-using-session-attributes-to-enable-repeat-responses), I am using `this.attributes.key` to store the session attributes.

```
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        database.startSession()
            .then(data => {
                // console.log(data); // data does have token
                this.attributes.token=data.token;
                // this.attributes['token']=data.token; // Tried this too
                this.emit(':ask', responses.launch, responses.launchReprompt);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                this.emit(":ask", responses.error);
            });
    }, 
    .... More handlers
}
```

However, the on launch command, I get this error,

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response

I see no error in logs.

This is my response (as visible in alexa test developer console)

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak> Ok, exiting App. </speak>"
            },
            "shouldEndSession": true
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-nodejs/1.0.25 Node/v8.10.0"
    }
}
```

As [per here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/08edaa00-59e2-46b7-aace-4080f2a87450/using-session-attributes-in-your-alexa-skill-to-enhance-the-voice-experience), the `sessionAttributes` should contain what I set as session variables using `this.attributes`, but this is somehow empty.

How can I resolve this?

Edit: If I comment out `this.attributes` line, I get the welcome message correctly.

This is my `startSession` function, if its helpful.

```
async function startSession() {
    return {
        token: await getToken(),
        ... More attributes
    };
}
```

Edit 2: Very wierd thing that I noticed. If I just do `this.attributes.token="foobar"`, the session attribute gets set correctly. So I am assuming there is a problem with my `async` function. Note that `console.log(data)` still prints the data correctly with `token` attribute.

Edit 3: Cloudwatch logs

> START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
>   2018-08-15T14:00:47.639Z      Warning: Application ID is not set
>   END RequestId:  REPORT RequestId:     Duration: 315.05
>   ms    Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB
>   START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
>   2018-08-15T14:00:47.749Z      Warning: Application ID is not set
>   2018-08-15T14:00:48.564Z      { token: 'token', filter:
>   'foobar'} END RequestId:  REPORT RequestId:   Duration:
>   849.98 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB   START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
>   2018-08-15T14:00:49.301Z     Warning: Application ID is not
>   set END RequestId:  REPORT RequestId:
>    Duration: 0.72 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size:
>   128 MB    Max Memory Used: 74 MB

Comment: Can you paste your sample data of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: { token: '<token-value>',
...
}

Comment: Can you share the error logged in cloudwatch

Comment: There is no error, still shared the log, as it is displayed in cloudwatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the max size of the `response` object is `24kb`, [reference1](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-format), [reference2](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/67), [reference3](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/59975/long-string-responses-are-failing.html).

My `data` size was way more than `24kb`. Hence the session attributes did not get stored, and it resulted in `exit` intent. The solution is to store it in some db like `DynamoDB`.

Special credits to [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669153/will).